# Heap Memory issues using log4j to display the response

Tags: java, out-of-memory, heap-memory

There is a `log4j` logger with the level set to INFO in my code as follows:

```
String response = "";
response = someRemoteAPICall();
LOGGER.info("Response: "+response); //line 3
```

So at line 3 of this code, I am getting large heap dumps with OutOfMemory Error.

Is it possible to get OOM just from displaying log message.

My dump analysis shows the following `Shallow Heap` and `Retained Heap`:

[image]

[image]

Can this problem only be resolved by commenting out that LOG statement OR by settting the LEVEL to DEBUG instead of INFO OR some other elegant way is there?

Here I am lost..

**UPDATE:**

```
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        response = new StringBuffer();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) { //OOM
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
```

The same is happening in the above code for the large data to read.

This is the image showing retained heap for this code with respect to the shallow heap:

[image]

**My System Properties:**

`java.runtime.name - Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment`

`java.runtime.version - 1.8.0_51-b16`

`java.vm.specification.name - Java Virtual Machine Specification`

`java.vm.specification.vendor - Oracle Corporation`

`java.vm.specification.version - 1.8`

`java.vm.name - Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM`

`os.arch - amd64`

`os.name - Linux`

`os.version - 3.13.0-61-generic`

Comment: Logging an entire response at INFO level is not usually wise, if the response can be large.

Comment: ok but at least I want to hold that response, then parse it and send it to some third party server. Holding it to `StringBuffer/StringBuilder/String` causes OOM.

Answer (score 2):

Oh, yes, it can.

You have a **String concatenation using +** in your logging line. This implies, a *new* String with a *new* char array will be created before the log happens.

And if by chance the `toString()` of your object uses similar features, you might end up not with *one* but with *many* copies of your char[] - which was not too small to begin with.

If you absolutely **must** print out that whole thing, you'd be better of with

```
LOGGER.info("Response: %s", response);
```

Which would only output the String if logging INFO is actually enabled.

If you *know* your file's big and you want to preserve it still, you could do somthing like this:

```
 if(LOGGER.isInfoEnabled()) {
    File dump = writeToDumpFile(response);
    LOGGER.info("Response written to %s", dump.getAbsolutePath());
 }
```

(And create + implement `writeToDumpFile(Response response)` of cause)

**Update on your Update**

You don't know how long the *line* will be.

Instead try:

```
InputStreamReaderin = new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream());
response = new StringBuilder();
char[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int len = in.read(buffer);
while(len > 0 ) {
    response.append(buffer, 0, len);
    len = in.read(buffer);        
}
in.close();
```

With readLine() you *once again* created a copy of the whole string :-)

If you only want to dump *part* of your response, you could do right after first read...

Comment: So should I remove that LOG statement or should I simply change the level of logging to DEBUG for testing purposes?

Comment: Check your response.toString() - there might be hidden treasures there as well.

Comment: I am getting compile time error with your code as: The method `info(Object, Throwable)` in the type Category is not applicable for the arguments (String, String).

Comment: Oh well. for the Logger with `, response`? I guess then you'd have to do `, response.toString())` in which case checking the loglevel outside will be the smart thing to do in order to only invoke this is absolutely necessary

Comment: Response is already a String variable so why to do `response.toString()`? Also, what is the purpose of condition to check `LOGGer.isInfoEnable()` when the level to print the response is already INFO?

Comment: Scratch that then. Possibly different log4j versions

Comment: Class org.apache.log4j.Logger


This is the central class in the log4j package. Most logging operations, except configuration, are done through this class.
`Since:log4j 1.2`      and    `Author:Ceki Gülcü`

Comment: You could always do two lines: LOGGER.info ("Response:"); LOGGER.info (response);

Comment: Did that help with the issue you had?

Comment: No, I used the substring to print the data part in case it is large. However, now I am getting OOM at `while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {`. See the update.

Comment: See my edit. You don't by chance can just throw mire memory atbthe jvm? What are your system specs, which runtime options did you choose?

Comment: I suspect if this will work although your code looks promising. I included the image to my previous code in the question. Please take a look. So don't you think that when `StringBuilder` will reach the max append limit then it will also throw the OOM later according to your this code.

Comment: Well if you're that low on memory already that additional 66m don't fit you might run into trouble pretty fast again. However, the loop in this case will only read 1k of data at a time and use this to fill the Builder. As I remember, you were able to hold the response in memory *once* anyway. Only at the "+" operation for the logging duplicated were created exhausting your memory.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you shouldn't dump your whole response. Might it occur, that it results in 66MB of String data?

Oh, and even a simple statement like

```
Object o = new Object();
```

may result in an OutOfMemory, if it is completely full.

Comment: So should I remove that LOG statement or should I simply change the level of logging to DEBUG for testing purposes?